# Install MariaDB Archive Engine

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mariadb

I have installed [MariaDB on my Debian](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=vpsFree&distro=Debian&distro_release=wheezy&version=10.1) but [Archive Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/archive/) is missing.
Is there any way how to install Archive Engine?

I haven't file ha_archive in my /usr/lib/mysql/plugin directory

Comment: What is the error message when you create an table with archive engine this way:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archive (id int(11) NOT NULL, content text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL) ENGINE=ARCHIVE;`

Comment: Warning (Code 1286): Unknown storage engine 'ARCHIVE'

Comment: I've created a ticket for this issue: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7151

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to install plugin using SQL shell.

> MariaDB> INSTALL PLUGIN archive SONAME 'ha_archive.so';

Show Plugins

> MariaDB> show engines \G

## EDIT:

I have installed mariadb-10.x on ubuntu and `ARCHIVE` is by default enabled.

> MariaDB> show engines \G

```
*************************** 7. row ***************************
      Engine: ARCHIVE
     Support: YES
     Comment: Archive storage engine
Transactions: NO
          XA: NO
  Savepoints: NO
```

Comment: MariaDB [test]> INSTALL PLUGIN archive SONAME 'ha_archive.so';

ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_archive.so' (errno: 2, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Comment: Try 'dpkg -L maridadb' it will list all the files included in package. I believe your deb packages doesn't contain ha_archive.so

Comment: You are right. My .deb package doesn't contain this file. I really don't wanna compile it by self, but all official .deb packages from official mirror (https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=vpsFree&distro=Debian&distro_release=wheezy&version=10.1) are evidently without this file.

Comment: which version you are installing on which `OS`? is it `10.x` or `5.x` ?

Comment: The ARCHIVE Storage Engine was enabled by default until MariaDB 10.0. From MariaDB 10.1, the plugin needs to be specifically enabled. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/archive/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by entering the following command in MariaDB by logging as a root user -

```
MariaDB [(none)]> INSTALL SONAME 'ha_archive';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)
```

Check if it is installed -

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```